# lapply and passing arguments

Tags: r, lapply

I'm trying to learn how to effectivly use the apply family in R.  I have the following numeric vector

```
>aa
 [1] 0.047619 0.000000      NaN 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
 [9]      NaN      NaN 0.000000      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
[17] 0.000000 0.000000      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
[25]      NaN 0.100000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000      NaN
[33]      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN 0.133333      NaN
[41]      NaN 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
[49]      NaN
```

and I'm trying to get the `n` factor out of `pwr.t.test` with each of these as an input to the `d` argument.

My attempt(s) have yielded this as the latest result, and frankly, I'm stumped...> `lapply(aa,function(x) pwr.t.test(d=x,power=.8,sig.level=.05,type="one.sample",alternative="two.sided"))`

with the following error message:

```
Error in uniroot(function(n) eval(p.body) - power, c(2 + 1e-10, 1e+07)) : 
  f() values at end points not of opposite sign
```

Any ideas on the right way to do this?

Comment: You seem to be doing it correctly, but are you sure that function will play nice with values 0.000000 and NaN?

Comment: You are correct!  It hates those inputs...It looks like it only wants non-zero numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: The number of subjects needed is greater than the maximum that R will check for.  Add some checks so that you don't run the function when `d == 0` and it will work.

When `d = 0`, you need an infinite number of subjects to detect the difference.  The error you are seeing is because R tries to calculate power numerically.  The algorithm R uses first checks the bounds of the interval over which the possible values for `N` lie (about `2` to `1e+07`).  Because the function for power has the same sign at both endpoints of the interval and is monotonic in `N`, R throws an error saying that the root (the value of `N` you are looking for) cannot be found.